# Where can I get list of open Ethereum nodes so I can use the RPC calls?

Tags: json-rpc, nodes

In Bitcoin I can use the rpc calls to manage the node or broadcast transactions. How can this be done with Ethereum?

- Is there a list of public open nodes I can use?
- How can I do this in the browser using javascript?

Comment: sorry i mean RPC... typo..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most easily-accessible source of "public" Ethereum nodes is probably Infura (https://infura.io/). There is also something called QuickNode (https://quiknode.io/), but I think their nodes are time limited. Infura's nodes are open to the public, but I've seen mention that it may not be forever.

Answer (score 0):

QuikNode now has a 100% free tier on their `QuikNode API` service. You get access to Ethereum MainNet just by registering an account [QuikNode.io](https://quiknode.io)

Answer (score 0):

I have experience using [nownodes.io](https://nownodes.io), which has worked well for me for over a year. They also have a testnet for ETH, which is easy to test with a free trial.