# how to broadcast ethereum signed transaction without web3.js or any other web3 library/client

Tags: web3js

Is there any secure and reliable way of broadcasting signed Ethereum transaction without using Web3 library like with some service and some sort of HTTP API?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use a library for this? All the library does is call the HTTP API. You can write your own code to do that, but why?

Comment: there are some small targets like embedded devices where you can't fit web3 library, so you need HTTP API but for what node?) If you are a company that don't want to or can't rely on the third party - seems you need your own node and own HTTP API

Answer (score 1):

I thought I did good research, but its a duplicate, with many answers, for example, [Where can I get list of open Ethereum nodes so I can use the RPC calls?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29748/where-can-i-get-list-of-open-ethereum-nodes-so-i-can-use-the-rpc-calls)

Just any available node with RPC API. Or make your own one ;)