# Send different signed transactions in a batch?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I have signed transactions and want to make a batch request with all the different signed transactions. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can broadcast them with RPC nodes : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74713/how-to-broadcast-ethereum-signed-transaction-without-web3-js-or-any-other-web3-l

Comment: I use a private network for all my transactions

Comment: there is no batch functionality in Ethereum, you send them one by one via RPC